# Time threads in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading

**How can i split a c++ program into 2 time streams?**

The task looks like this: a random element is added to the variety every t seconds, while a random element is deleted from the variety every n seconds. N and t are randomly selected number.

I have an idea of reccurent function, but actually I don't know, how to realize it.

Comment: [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread). make certain that the resources shared between the threads are protected form concurrent access in some way. [`std::mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) may help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## One (unsynchronized) approach

With C++11 and newer you can use `std::thread`, `std::mutex`, and `std::atomic` to do something like

```
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

void n_function(varietyType variety, int n);

std::mutex mtx;
std::atomic<int> time = 0;
int end = 0;      // This must be given a value greater than zero for anything to happen

int main() {
  int t;      // These must be assigned a value larger than zero
  int n;      // Additionally, they are type-agnostic - they don't have to be int,
              // if the rest of this example code is modified accordingly.

  std::thread n_thread(n_function, variety, n);

  int prev = time;
  while (time < end) {
    time += 1;
    if (time - prev >= t) {
      prev = time;
      mtx.lock();
      // add element
      mtx.unlock();
    }
  }
  n_thread.join();
}
```

where `n_function` is

```
void n_function(varietyType variety, int n) {
  int prev = time;
  while (time < end) {
    if (time - prev >= n) {
      prev = time;
      mtx.lock();
      // delete element
      mtx.unlock();
    }
  }
}
```

#### Note

- This will work very quickly (except the mutexing) but since the threads are not lock-stepped it is prone to missing deletions (i.e. go for 1000 steps with `n_h = 4` might only do 241 deletions instead of the 250 it is supposed to), particularly if elements are deleted more frequently than added. Furthermore, the speed with which an element can be added or deleted will have an effect - faster addition/deletion increases probability of a miss.
- If you want to tie this to your CPU clock and have `t` and `n` seconds reflect *actual* times in 'wall-clock' seconds I would recommend looking at `std::chrono` instead of using an atomic counter.
- For longer time intervals use `std::atomic<unsigned long> time` or even `std::atomic<unsigned long long> time` as needed.

## Another (synchronized) Approach

If speed is less important than accuracy (and the reality is for most use cases these two approaches will be very close in speed) then it might be better to use three threads (two children, one parent) to modify the variety. i.e.

```
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

std::mutex mtx;

void n_function(varietyType variety, int n);
void t_function(varietyType variety, int t);

std::atomic<int> check = 0;
std::atomic<int> time = 0;
int end = 0;      // This must be given a value greater than zero for anything to happen

int main() {
  int t;        // Again these must be given a value greater than 0
  int n;
  std::thread n_thread(n_function, variety, n);
  std::thread t_thread(t_function, variety, t);

  while (time < end) {
    time += 1;
    check = 2;
    while (check != 0) {}    // blocking wait loop - use caution
  }
  n_thread.join();
  t_thread.join();
}
```

Where `t_function` and `n_function` are

```
void t_function(varietyType variety, int t) {
    int prev = time;
    while (time < end) {
        if (time - prev >= t && check > 0) {
          prev = time;
          mtx.lock();
          // add element
          mtx.unlock();
        }
        check --;
    }
}

void n_function(varietyType variety, int n) {
    int prev = time;
    while (time < end) {
        if (time - prev >= n && check > 0) {
          prev = time;
          mtx.lock();
          // add element
          mtx.unlock();
        }
        check --;
    }
}
```

#### Note

- Both approaches assume `variety` is shared memory, either declared as a pointer or explicitly declared as shared memory.
- Both of these methods may (and likely will) be more inefficient than a single threaded approach, unless the addition/deletion of an element is computationally expensive (i.e. if there is significant calculation involved in decided to remove or if an element has a large memory footprint).
- Personally synchronous approaches like that where the threads have to wait for each other make me nervous because if any of them hang for whatever reason then the whole thing hangs - depending on the application that could be worse than only one or some threads hanging.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Very helpful answer